# Execute code after set amount of frames

Tags: python, timer, pygame

```
while True:
    clock.tick(75)
```

Now, if I'm not mistaken this should run the rest of the code under the while loop 75 times a second. But how would I make a certain piece of code under the while loop execute half as many times or 75 times in two seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import count

for i in count():
    clock.tick(75)
    # do stuff
    if i%2:
        # do stuff at half speed
```

Comment: Overlooked the obvious my mistake